# Django-voting: what is the right way of appending tags

Tags: django, django-tagging

i'm starting with django-tagging and I don't understand why `update_tags(object, new_tag)` method **replaces** all existing tags on `object` by `new_tag`.

What is the proper way to append a tag to the existing tags on an object inside a views?

EDIT: `add_tag` function is not satifying becaus it doesn't enables you to add multiple words tags: see [this former post](http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg65560.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `add_tag(object, tag_name)`.

For more information see http://api.rst2a.com/1.0/rst2/html?uri=http://django-tagging.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/overview.txt#api-reference

Comment: yes, this works but i don't understand the logic: in your Tagged_Item tables you have a line for each tag even if it on the same object...

Comment: Correct. TaggedItem is a many-to-many relation, one is created for every object-tag link. Tag is the entity that represents a tag.